# Print the number of pages in the document before this page

Tags: page-numbering

I'd like to print a sentence like this:

"written upon this page and the *n* preceding pages of paper"

where *n* is the number of pages *before* this page.

`\thepage` gives me the current page number, so really I just want `\thepage - 1`. I've been trying to look at performing some math in LaTeX, but I can't seem to find anything.

I've also looked at the `lastpage` package (which could work, because this sentence is actually going on the last page of the document), but I'd still need to subtract 1 from it.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to kan/gekkostate, here's the result that does exactly what I wanted:

```
...
\newcounter{precedingpages}
\setcounter{precedingpages}{\thepage}
\addtocounter{precedingpages}{-1}
written upon this page and the \theprecedingpages{} preceding pages of paper
...
```

Comment: You could define a new counter that is triggered whenever \thepage is and \addtocounter{newcounter}{-1}.

Comment: @Kan I was just about to recommend that!

Comment: @kan Totally works! Can you submit an answer and I'll upvote/give you the answer for it? I've edited my question with the final result.

Answer (score 3):

Using `\thepage` might produce undesired results due to the asynchronous nature of page building mechanism. Using a `\label`, `\ref` approach can prevent the undesired results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{abc}

\newcommand\prevtopage{%
  \stepcounter{abc}
  \label{page\theabc}written upon this page and the  \the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{page\theabc}-1\relax\ preceding page(s) of paper.}

\begin{document}

\prevtopage
\clearpage
\prevtopage

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This answer is nice because it looks like I could reuse the command all over the document as a one-liner without having to keep defining counters like my current approach.

Comment: @aardvarkk yes, you can resuse `\prevtopage` as many times as you wish, but another (main) advantage is that it will give always the right results, unlike the `\thepage` approach.